# How do I ignore an error message when using Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm not a very good programmer (like at all), so I got pretty excited when I discovered Apple's automator tool. I've made a really rough web crawler using Extract URL> Get Specified URL > Get Text From Webpage > Extract Data > New Text Document. However for of the URLs are throwing error messages when the Automator starts the "Get Text From Webpage" process. I know that I can write some apple-script to get around this problem, but I'm having difficulty implementing it.

Multiple threads have alluded a try statement such as:

```
 try
   --do what ever
 on error
   --continue with code
 end
```

The issue comes with how to code the "Get text from page" and the "on error, continue with code"

Could someone help?

Comment: You'll need to put an applescript action in there that tests for a valid URL. Then, the on error would end the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method to grab the source code of a webpage and drop it into a file using shell script in applescript:

```
do shell script " curl 'http://www.google.com' | cat >> '/users/compName/desktop/test.txt'"
```

There are many things you can do with this, but it's an easy start.